# How to make showData() give separate results for different data types?

Tags: java, class, io

The main class...

```
import java.io.*;
public class RecMain
{
    public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException
    {
        Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(5.3f,7.2f);
        Rectangle rec2 = new Rectangle();
        Rectangle rec3 = new Rectangle(12378438,37648363);



        rec1.showData();
        rec2.showData();
        rec3.showData();

    }
}
```

And the Rectangle class

```
import java.io.*;
class Rectangle
{

    private int len=0, bdt=0;
    private float len2=0, bdt2=0;
    public Rectangle()
    {
    }
    public Rectangle(int length, int breadth)
    {
        len=length;
        bdt=breadth;
    }
    public Rectangle(float length, float breadth)
    {
        len2=length;
        bdt2=breadth;
    }
    public void setData() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        len2=Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
        bdt2=Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
    }
    public void showData()
    {
        System.out.println("Length: "+len+"\nBreadth: "+bdt);
        System.out.println("Length: "+len2+"\nBreadth: "+bdt2);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is, use the same showData() for all objects, so that for rec1, the result will be len2 and bdt2, while for rec3 it will be len and bdt. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if to check if len is 0 or len2 is 0 and then show results accordingly.
So, if len is 0, you can print len2 and bdt2. Else, show len and bdt.

Comment: But what if I use rec1.showData() again in the end of the main class? Then that is not gonna work, right? Because both len and len2 have a value, and none of them is 0.

Comment: No, it will work correctly. Because your rec1 instance has only len2 and bdt2 variables set. rec3 instance doesn't affect rec1 instance. They are two separate objects having separate properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use generics, you may get rid of duplicating rectangle parameters:

```
abstract class Rectangle<T extends Number> {
    protected T len, bdt;

    Rectangle() {}

    Rectangle(T length, T breadth) {
        this.len = length;
        this.bdt = breadth;
    }

    public void showData() {
        System.out.println("Length: " + len + ", breadth: " + bdt);
    }

    public abstract void setData() throws IOException;
}

//----- test -----
Rectangle<Float> rec1 = new Rectangle<Float>(5.3f, 7.2f) {
    @Override
    public void setData() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        len =Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
        bdt =Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
    }
};

Rectangle<Integer> rec2 = new Rectangle<Integer>(2, 3) {
    @Override
    public void setData() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        len =Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        bdt =Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());    
    }
};
rec1.showData();
rec2.showData();
```

output:

```
Length: 5.3, breadth: 7.2
Length: 2, breadth: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why you are having `private int len=0, bdt=0;` in your code at all? Why don't you just get rid of them?

Like this:

```
import java.io.*;
class Rectangle {
    private float length, breadth;
    public Rectangle() {
    }

    public Rectangle(float length, float breadth) {
        this.length = length;
        this.breadth = breadth;
    }

    public void setData() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        length = Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
        breadth = Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
    }

    public void showData() {
        System.out.println("Length: "+length+"\nBreadth: "+breadth);
    }
}
```

Theo code from `RecMain` would still compile.

PS: I wonder why you truncated `length` and `breadth` to `len` and `bdt` in your original code. That made it harder to read.

PPS: I would also change the `float` to `double` in your code.

---

If you need the Rectangle with int for a reason, I would use a separate class for that with a common interface:

```
interface Rectangle {
   void setData() throws IOException;
   void showData();
}
```

Then implement the interface like that:

```
class IntRectangle implements Rectangle {
    private int length, breadth;
    public Rectangle() {
    }

    public Rectangle(int length, int breadth) {
        this.length = length;
        this.breadth = breadth;
    }

    public void setData() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        length = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        breadth = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }

    public void showData() {
        System.out.println("Length: "+length+"\nBreadth: "+breadth);
    }
}
```

The same for the class with the `float` (rename it to `FloatRectangle`).